# Largest even number in a list using fold

Tags: python, fold

I want to accomplish this:

- Construct a function that takes in a list as a parameter and returns the biggest even number in that list.
- Do this by using the "fold" function in Python

I thought it might be something along the lines of:

```
def fold(f, v, l):
    for x in l:
        v = f(v, x)
    return v

def biggest_even_number(xs):
    l = [i for i in xs if i % 2 == 0]
    return fold(l)
```

I know this is wrong but I just don't know how to set this up. How would I accomplish the above task using the "fold" function?

Comment: Do you need to use your own version of `fold()`? Python provides `reduce()` as a builtin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fold` function looks good. You just need to call it with correct arguments:

```
def biggest_even_number(xs):
    l = [i for i in xs if i % 2 == 0]
    return fold(max, float("-inf"), l)
```

If it is not a homework, you can use builtin [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) which basically does the same thing:

```
def biggest_even_number(xs):
    l = [i for i in xs if i % 2 == 0]
    return reduce(max, l, float("-inf"))
```

Thanks to [@Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski), for anyone trying to find the maximum value of a sequence, you don't even need `reduce`:

```
def biggest_even_number(xs):
    return max(i for i in xs if i % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: `def biggest_even_number(xs): return max(i for i in xs if i %2 == 0)`  No reduce needed. Good answer. Bad homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like the following:

```
def fold(l):
    biggest = float("-inf")
    for i in l:
        biggest = max(i, biggest)
    return biggest

def biggest_even_number(xs):
    l = [i for i in xs if i % 2 == 0]
    return fold(l)
```